# Approximation of Binomial distribution with Poisson

Tags: probability-distributions

I have to prove $\sup|P_{n}(k)-\pi_{\lambda}(k)| \leq \frac{\lambda^2}{n}$ where $P_{n}(k)$ is distribution of Binomial RV with parameters $(n, \frac{\lambda}{n})$ and $\pi_{\lambda}(k)$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$.

I've shown that if $\xi=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\xi_j$, where $\xi_j \sim \text{Ber} \left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$ and $\eta=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \eta_j$, where $\eta_j \sim \text{Poi} \left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$, then $\xi$ has probability distribution $P_{n}(k)$ and $\eta \ \pi_{\lambda}(k)$.

Any suggestions will be massively appreciated.

Comment: There isn't any "then" after your "if", so it's not clear to me what you are saying you have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See pages 20-21 of the book Stochastic processes and models, by David Stirzaker, [here](http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.com/pdf/13/9780198568148.pdf).

Adapting the linked solution to your case and notation: Using your notation, choose a joint distribution $f(x,y)$ for $\xi_j$ and $\eta_j$ as follows:
$$
f(0,0) = 1 - \lambda /n,
$$
$$
f(1,0) = e^{ - \lambda /n}  - 1 + \lambda /n,
$$
$$
f(1,y) = \frac{{(\lambda /n)^y e^{ - \lambda /n} }}{{y!}}, \;\; y \geq 1,
$$
$$
f(0,y) = 0,\;\; y \geq 1.
$$
Note that $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ indeed determines a joint distribution, as
$$
f(0,0) + f(1,0) + \sum\limits_{y = 1}^\infty  {f(1,y)}  + f(0,y) = 1.
$$
Further note that $\xi_j$ and $\eta_j$ are not independent with this joint distribution. It holds
$$
{\rm P}(\xi _j  \ne \eta _j ) = f(1,0) + {\rm P}(\eta _j  \ge 2) = \lambda /n - (\lambda /n)e^{ - \lambda /n}  \le (\lambda /n)^2 .
$$
Next, using your notation,
$$
|{\rm P}(\xi  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k)| \le {\rm P}(\xi  \ne \eta ) \le {\rm P}(\xi _j  \ne \eta _j ,\;{\rm for}\;{\rm some}\; j)
$$
(the second inequality is trivial; the first is derived in the edit below).
Thus,
$$
|{\rm P}(\xi  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k)| \leq \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{\rm P}(\xi _j  \ne \eta _j )}  \leq \frac{{\lambda ^2 }}{n},
$$
and so
$$
|P_n (k) - \pi _\lambda  (k)| \le \frac{{\lambda ^2 }}{n}.
$$

EDIT: Derivation of the inequality
$$
|{\rm P}(\xi  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k)| \le {\rm P}(\xi  \ne \eta ) .
$$
From
$$
{\rm P}(\xi  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k) = {\rm P}(\xi  = k,\eta  \ne k) + {\rm P}(\xi  = k,\eta  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k),
$$
it follows that
$$
{\rm P}(\xi  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k) \leq {\rm P}(\xi  = k,\eta  \ne k) \leq {\rm P}(\xi \neq \eta).
$$
Analogously, ${\rm P}(\eta  = k) - {\rm P}(\xi  = k) \leq {\rm P}(\xi \neq \eta)$; hence the result.

Also, in view of the proof (above the edit), it is worth noting that
$$
{\rm P}(\xi _j  \ne \eta _j ,\;{\rm for}\;{\rm some}\; j) = {\rm P}(\xi_1 \neq \eta_1  \vee \cdots \vee \xi_n \neq \eta_n) \leq \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{\rm P}(\xi _j  \ne \eta _j )} .
$$

Comment: Further note that the joint distribution $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ yields the correct marginal distributions for $\xi_j$ and $\eta_j$.

Comment: I can see that $\frac{\lambda}{n} -\frac{\lambda}{n}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{n}} \leq \frac{\lambda}{n}$, but why is it less than $\Big(\frac{\lambda}{n}\Big)^2$?

Comment: @sigma.z.1980: Let $x=\lambda / n \,( > 0)$, so you want to show $x - xe^{-x} \leq x^2$, or (after dividing by $x$) $1 - e^{-x} \leq x$. The last inequality can be easily proved by comparing the derivatives of $1 - e^{-x}$ and $x$, which are $e^{-x}$ and $1$, respectively.

Comment: OK yes of course, it's just Taylor series expansion of $e^{-x}$ till the 2nd term. I regret I didn't see this before.

Comment: @sigma: Note, however, that from $e^{-x} = 1 - x + x^2/2! - x^3/3! + \cdots$ it is not clear that $e^{-x} \geq 1 - x$ (though it is true).

Comment: that is because positive term is larger than the following negative one, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @sigma: But $x^3 / 3! > x^2 / 2!$ for $x > 3$. I recommend proving the inequality $1-e^{-x} \leq x$ by comparing derivatives, as indicated above.

Comment: I got the point. For the second inequality, $|P(\xi=k)-P(\eta-k)| \leq P(\xi \neq \eta)$, do I have to show explicitly that $|\binom{n}{k}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k}-e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}| \leq \frac{\lambda}{n}-\frac{\lambda}{n}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{n}}$?

Comment: @sigma: No. I'll show how to derive that inequality later on.

Comment: @sigma: Done...

Comment: Do you think you made a typo here? The sum should be the upper bound $|{\rm P}(\xi  = k) - {\rm P}(\eta  = k)| \le {\rm P}(\xi  \ne \eta ) \le {\rm P}(\xi _j  \ne \eta _j ,\;{\rm for}\;{\rm some}\; j)$, since you sum over $j$ ro obtain the inequality

Comment: OK, so you used the law of total probability and then Boole's inequality

Comment: @sigma: Since $\xi \neq \eta$ implies $\xi_j \neq \eta_j$ for some $j$, ${\rm P}(\xi \neq \eta) \leq {\rm P}(\xi_j \neq \eta_j,\;{\rm for}\;{\rm some}\; j)$.

Comment: but of course! I regret this problem wan't touched upon in any of my stats courses. I don't find it easy at all, although it is supposed to be.